# Hanging request ram issue

Tags: php

I would like to provide a PHP hanging request that will stay open until new events exists, at which point it will immediately return back JSON encoded data to javascript client.

Connection -> wait for events (check, sleep, check, sleep, etc) -> event is detected -> send events back -> close request.

CPU load is no issue with this configuration, but the amount of RAM required to scale is about 5-10MB per user because each connection requires 1 PHP proc. Is there a way to allow a single PHP process to be used to server more than 1 connection at the same time. Also is it possible to do this without using some type of listening daemon service?

Comment: sounds like a basic web service?

Comment: Why does the process have to hang around? It can certainly be done but at great cost to Server configuration and resources. Plus, it is not fail safe. What if "your" PHP thread aborts, hangs up, or the server restarts? Why not use classic persistence models like sessions and make a new request on every event?

Comment: it's for an interactive game, that requires close to real time responses, and polling every .5-2 seconds is going to use even more resources than a hanging request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's for an interactive game, that
>   requires close to real time responses,
>   and polling every .5-2 seconds is
>   going to use even more resources than
>   a hanging request

In this case PHP is definitely is NOT a solution to your problem. Consider something like C++, Delphi or .NET to write a webservice. You are trying to eat soup using a fork...

Comment: Thank you for restoring my faith in the world's sanity level.

Comment: That was my plan of attack, but I was hoping I could find a solution that work on a cloud hosting solution instead of a custom setup.